# How to get better test reports in the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a fairly simple karma.config.js file

```
basePath = '../';


files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'js/lib/angular*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = true;
browsers = ['PhantomJS'];
```

When I run `karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run` I'm getting the following output

```
$ karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run
[2013-06-24 23:47:08.750] [DEBUG] config - autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id LwMoWxzIbSUuBsvIqB_m
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac): Executed 6 of 6 SUCCESS (0.073 secs / 0.02 secs)
```

I've been searching for something to tell me how to get the output of the tests that get logged (e.g. `SUCCESS Unit: services myService should behave`)

The only way I can see the output of the tests is to open Chrome and click 'Debug', then show the developer tools console. I want the messages to be logged out to the terminal, but I cannot figure out how to get this working.

Comment: Terrible tittle for this question

Comment: Yeah. If I remember correctly I rage-typed that title after trying to figure it out for way too long. It's a good thing Google searches more than titles.

Comment: @brettof86 Someone has mangled the title of this question. It obviously has nothing to do with HTML when reading the question itself. I was going to try to replace the title, but after thinking a bit, I don't think I understand the question enough to do that. (What's unclear to me is if you're looking for a simple report mechanism or if you want to capture some form of output from within the test itself.) Could you revise it?

Comment: You're right, it had nothing to do with HTML. I was looking for a console reporter and for karma-spec-reporter specifically. I edited the title again and removed "HTML."

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Fixed by installing the [karma-spec-reporter](https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter)

`npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev`

and adding this my karma.config.js

`reporters: ['spec'],`

According to [karma documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/plugins.html)

> By default, Karma loads all NPM modules that are siblings to it and their name matches karma-*.

but some users have had to add the following to their config

`plugins: ['karma-spec-reporter']`

Comment: It didn't work for me until I specified in the karma.conf.js file karma-spec-reporter as a plugin; this is how my plugins array looks plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-spec-reporter'
        ], note karma-spec-reporter at the end

Comment: Yes you have to tell the config that you're using this plugin.

Comment: If all of your plugins start with `karma-` then you don't have to reference any of them. The default behaviour is to load all `karma-*` plugins. http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/plugins.html

Comment: Works as @blues_driven and brettof86 described it.

Comment: Same here.. had to add the plugin.. I went ahead and proposed an edit to this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Just another detail - if you keep the default reporter 'progress' in the **karma.config.js**, like below:

```
reporters: ["progress", "spec"]
```

or another console reporter, the "spec" reporter output won't work.

You should keep only the "spec" one, or the "spec" with other browser reporters. For example:

```
reporters: ["spec", "coverage"]
```

Comment: True, had the same problem. reporters: ["spec", "coverage"] works

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a reporter to make the output more readable: **karma-helpful-reporter**

Has some nice customization options: https://github.com/whyboris/karma-helpful-reporter

Instal instructions inside, basically `npm install --save-dev karma-helpful-reporter` and then add to the Karma configuration plugins section:

```
plugins: [ 
  require('karma-helpful-reporter')
],
reporters: [ 'helpful' ],
```

Comment: This is real nice. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [Karma-mocha-reporter](https://github.com/litixsoft/karma-mocha-reporter)
 as reporter and you should have a clean report in your console.

```
npm i karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev

// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // reporters configuration
    reporters: ['mocha']
  });
};
```

Sometimes, e.g in `@angular/cli` environment you should require this like:

```
plugins: [
   ...
   require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working (draft) configuration without the section 'plugins' (actually I don't fully understand why I should need to specify them ...):

***package.json***

```
  "devDependencies": {
    [...]
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.24",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.13"
  }
```

***karma.conf.js***

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        reporters: ['spec'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
    });
};
```

***Gruntfile.js***

```
    karma: {
        options: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            files: [
                'app/libs/angular.js',
                'app/libs/angular-resource.js',
                'app/libs/angular-route.js',
                [...] 
                'app/modules/**/*-spec.js'
            ]
        },
        unit: {
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
```

Now when I run `grunt karma` messages from the `*-spec.js` files (`describe('message', function() ...)`) are displayed nicely in the console.